# Android Format String into minutes and seconds

Tags: android, json, string, gdata

I am parsing YouTube JSON-C GDATA feeds and as it is JSON it can not contain a colon (:) so when I parse the string duration it comes as plain text i.e 823 or 2421. how would I format this to be more readable? i.e 823 --> 8:23 or 2421 --> 24.21 or 23 --> 0:23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
String time = "322";
int length = time.length();
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(time);

switch(length) {
    case(1):    s.insert(0, "0:0"); break; //ex: 2 -> 0:02
    case(2):    s.insert(0, "0:"); break; //ex: 22 -> 0.22
    case(3):    s.insert(1, ":"); break;  //ex: 322 -> 3:22
    case(4):    s.insert(2, ":"); break; //ex: 2421 -> 24:21
}
```

And you can continue to add `case(5)` if you expect a length in hours.

Good Luck!

Comment: i added the code like this: http://pastebin.com/ajCVfUYr but when I run it comes up like this: http://imgur.com/N72zi ???

Comment: You should put `s` in the map instead of `time`: `map.put(KEY_VIDEODURATIONFORMATTED, s);`. We made the insertion on `s`.

Answer (score 1):

I want to strictly answer your question, the answer is:

```
//Check the length of the string and maybe add zero at the beginning
string = StringBuffer(string).insert(2, ":").toString();
```

Note: I should have used string.getLength()-2, but I hope you got the point ;-)

But, personally, I would send the time in seconds or in an other format.

```
String dateStr = "03/08/2010"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

Comment: If talking about changing sent data format unix timesstamp would be best bet, not?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/parsedate.html

That should help ;)